# Google Sheets data validation dropdown will not show if cell contains formula

Tags: google-sheets, data-validation

I have a data validation dropdown with a list of possible values, and if the cell is empty or has a value, the dropdown list will show correctly.

But if the cell contains a formula, the dropdown list will not show and clicking on the dropdown arrow will enter cell editing.

Is this by design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pretty much yes, to return on selectable items on dropdown menu you need to select a cell and delete it with <kbd>Delete</kbd>

to avoid it use green aproach:
[image]
[image]